# Callback when Keyboard Dismiss in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a date picker and a text input in my screen. To avoid ugly transitions, I want to dismiss the keyboard before showing the date picker.

Currently, as I don't know how to invoke a callback when the Keyboard is dismissed, I am doing something like this:

```
 const showBirthdayPicker = () => {
    // Dismiss the keyboard to avoid ugly transitions
    Keyboard.dismiss();

    setTimeout(() => {
      datePickerRef.current.show();
    }, 500);
 };
```

This works, but this solution has a problem... If the keyboard was dismissed before running this function, the user will experiment an unnecessary delay of 0.5 secs...

Is there any other way to do this? I have been looking at the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboard.html) of Keyboard but no callback when dismissing.

Comment: You can set up a listener before triggering dismiss and remove it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the documentation, you can listen to the keyboardDidHide event to watch if the keyboard is dismissed. A quick example is following

```
  const showBirthdayPicker = () => {
    // Dismiss the keyboard to avoid ugly transitions
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', onKeyboardDidHide);
    Keyboard.dismiss();
  };
  const onKeyboardDidHide = (event) => {
    Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidHide', onKeyboardDidHide);
    datePickerRef.current.show();
  };
```

According to the document

> Note that if you set android:windowSoftInputMode to adjustResize or
> adjustPan, only keyboardDidShow and keyboardDidHide events will be
> available on Android. If you set android:windowSoftInputMode to
> adjustNothing, no events will be available on Android.
> keyboardWillShow as well as keyboardWillHide are generally not
> available on Android since there is no native corresponding event.

Comment: And will this solution show the DatePicker if the keyboard was dismissed at a first time? I mean, the callback is executed when the keyboard dissapears, or also if it was hidden 
since the beginning?

Comment: This will only work if the keyboard is open already.

Comment: Seems that I will have to listen the status of the Keyboard in the whole component life, and save it in the state "isKeyboardVisible" to conditionally run the Keyboard.dismiss in your solution...

Comment: Yeah, If your use case is like that then you can add another listener ```keyboardDidShow```, put it in the constructor to save status, and then run the code conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late, but I've made a simple object to alter the event driven behavior to async/await (which are basically a syntax sugar to promises).

```js
const myKeyboard = (() => {
  let resolve = () => {};
  let keyboardIsShowing = false;
  Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', () => {
    keyboardIsShowing = false;
    resolve(true)
  });
  Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', () => {
    keyboardIsShowing = true;
  })

  const dismiss = () => {
    return new Promise((p) => {
      if (keyboardIsShowing){
        resolve = p;
        Keyboard.dismiss();
      }
      else {
        p(true);
      }
    })
  }

  return {
    dismiss
  }
})();

// Then you can do:
await myKeyboard.dismiss();
datePickerRef.current.show();
```